# Is it possible to start new session without deleting old one [PHP]

Tags: php, session

Is it possible to start a new session if one is already running? I have two servers running simultaneously. My sessions are stored in a database. I want sessions to always be started based on a session id passed to the second server. The problem is the first session that was started is always read on the second server regardless the session id passed to it.

Comment: who about trying if else?

Answer (score 0):

you can set different session variable names for one or more session and to destroy simply use unset() function like unset($_session['admin_login']);

for front login like
$_session['front_login'] = array('username' => 'xyz', 'user_id' => 1);

for admin login like 
$_session['admin_login'] => array('admin_username' => 'qwerty', 'user_id' => 1);

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way to go about it. I read the session from the database and used session_decode() to populate the $_SESSION array.